# react - setState in short form

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Can you write

```
    let firstNameValid = this.state.firstNameValid;

    firstNameValid = value.length >= 1; 

    this.setState({ firstNameValid, firstNameValid,})
```

as short form syntax

```
this.setState({ firstNameValid})
```

I have tried the above code, it seems to work fine. 
Just wonder if it will have any side effect?

Comment: `this.setState({ firstNameValid })` is just sugar for `this.setState({ firstNameValid: firstNameValid })`. No side effects.

Comment: okay I see. thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.setState({ firstNameValid })` is just sugar for `this.setState({ firstNameValid: firstNameValid })`. No side effects.

These are called `shorthand property names`, and you can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions).

Answer (score 4):

react uses ES2015 ( with webpack and babel).

setState takes parameters which are objects.

In ES2015 `{ a : a }` is same as `{ a }` (object shorthand notation).

So `x = { a : a, b : b ...}` is same as `x = { a, b ..}`
So your code is perfectly valid and will not have any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean that you are writing

`this.setState({foo: foo})`

and now you are using `this.setState({ foo })`

there is not difference.

But `setState` will most likely have side effect, first because it is asynchronous and second because you are changing the whole component state and causing a render.

By the way this short way of assigning objects is a JS feature, nothing to do with react.